# How to deploy the REST server in hyperledger composer since all the containers in Docker Hub have been removed?

Tags: docker, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

as we can see in https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/composer-rest-server/tags all the docker containers in Hyperledger composer rest server images are removed. how are we supposed to deploy the rest server,as the official documentation says doing so this way.

Answer (score 0):

Composer has been sunset (it's been deprecated for a while) and it looks like all the docker hub images have been removed now.
Any documentation referring to using the docker images (rest server, cli, playground) won't work.

The source code for composer https://github.com/hyperledger/composer contains the Dockerfile's so you can always use them to build your own local docker image.

Comment: where can i find the source code that contain the Dockerfile???

Comment: how can i build a docker image from a source code, can you be a little descriptive since i'm having a hard in resolving this issue Mr.

Comment: You can find the docker file here https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-rest-server/docker/Dockerfile
So get this file (in whatever manner suites you) then use the docker cli to build using the `docker build` command. Recommend you go and read the docker cli reference to understand how this works and what options you need to provide to that command to get what you want.